# Single producer-multiple consumers: How to tell consumers that production is complete

Tags: c++

I my program a producer thread reads lines of text from a text file ( have about 8000 lines of text) and loads the lines into
a concurrent queue.

Three consumer threads read the lines from the queue each writing to a separate file.

When I run the program only the producer thread and only one of the consumer threads complete. The other two threads
seem to hang.

How do I reliably tell all consumer threads that the end of file has been reached so they should return
but making sure the queue is completely empty.

My platform is Windows 7 64-bit

VC11.

Code compiled as 64-bit and 32-bit got the same behavior.

Here is the code. (It is self-contained and compilable)

```
#include <queue>
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include <atomic>
#include <thread>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <mutex>
#include<string>
#include<memory>


template<typename Data>
class concurrent_queue
{
private:
    std::queue<Data> the_queue;
    mutable std::mutex the_mutex;
    std::condition_variable the_condition_variable;
public:
    void push(Data const& data){
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(the_mutex);
            the_queue.push(data);
        }
        the_condition_variable.notify_one();
    }

    bool empty() const{
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(the_mutex);
        return the_queue.empty();
    }

    const size_t size() const{
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(the_mutex);
        return the_queue.size();
    }

    bool try_pop(Data& popped_value){
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(the_mutex);
        if(the_queue.empty()){
            return false;
        }
        popped_value=the_queue.front();
        the_queue.pop();
        return true;
    }

    void wait_and_pop(Data& popped_value){
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(the_mutex);
        while(the_queue.empty()){
            the_condition_variable.wait(lock);
        }
        popped_value=the_queue.front();
        the_queue.pop();
    }
};

std::atomic<bool> done(true);
typedef std::vector<std::string> segment;
concurrent_queue<segment> data;
const int one_block = 15;

void producer()
{
    done.store(false);
    std::ifstream inFile("c:/sample.txt");
    if(!inFile.is_open()){
        std::cout << "Can't read from file\n";
        return;
    }

    std::string line;
    segment seg;
    int cnt = 0;
    while(std::getline(inFile,line)){
        seg.push_back(line);
        ++cnt;
        if( cnt == one_block ){
            data.push( seg );
            seg.clear();
            cnt = 0;
        }
    }
    inFile.close();
    done.store(true);
    std::cout << "all done\n";
}

void consumer( std::string fname)
{
    std::ofstream outFile(fname.c_str());
    if(!outFile.is_open()){
        std::cout << "Can't write to file\n";
        return;
    }

    do{
        while(!data.empty()){
            segment seg;
            data.wait_and_pop( seg );
            for(size_t i = 0; i < seg.size(); ++i)
            {
                outFile << seg[i] << std::endl;
            }
            outFile.flush();
        }
    } while(!done.load());
    outFile.close();
    std::cout << fname << "  done.\n";
}

int main()
{
    std::thread th0(producer);
    std::thread th1(consumer, "Worker1.txt");
    std::thread th2(consumer, "Worker2.txt");
    std::thread th3(consumer, "Worker3.txt");

    th0.join();
    th1.join();
    th2.join();
    th3.join();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach I'm using to terminate all threads waiting on a queue is to have a flag on the queue stating whether it is done which is tested before checking that there are element in the `pop()` function. If the flag indicates that the program should stop, any thread calling `pop()` throws an exception if there are no elements in the queue. When the flag is changed, the changing thread just calls `notify_all()` on the corresponding condition variable.

Comment: Have you looked at my usage of std::atomic<boo> bool? Basically this is my completion flag but it is not giving me the desired result

Comment: @SteveJessop: If there are objects in the queue, the thread just extracts the object and processes it. If there are no further elements in the queue the thread will see that it shouldn't wait and throw instead.

Comment: @DietmarKühl: oh yes, sorry.

Comment: @user841550: I fail to see where you call `notify_all()` to wake up all threads after the flag is set (in fact, I fail to see any call to `notify_all()`). Thus, I'm not too surprised that it doesn't give the results you want. Also, you want to check the flag in the loop where the thread is going to wait on the condition variable, not a loop outside that loop because the inner loop wouldn't have any reason to exit.

Comment: @Dietmar Kühl Do I declare / maintain a separate condition variable for my completion flag in addition to the one I have for the queue or one condition variable can be used for both the queue put and eof?

Comment: @user841550: You'd use the same condition variable for both the flag and the queue! After all, the waiting threads are actually waiting on the queue being empty and you need to wake them up to recheck the two conditions. As a result, I wouldn't use an atomic flag but rather synchronize the access to the flag using the same mutex as the queue: The waiting threads already lock that mutex anyway and there isn't any additional synchronization needed. Of course, the thread setting the flag would also need to acquire the lock to change the flag.

Comment: @Dietmar Kühl. Pleas bear with me if am following: Checking both conditions at the same time e.g. ( *!queue.empty()! && !done* ). 
It is possible that queue is non-empty but the producer is actually done i.e. 
already at end of file. i.e. consumer threads are bit behind in emptying the queue.

Comment: @user841550: The first question to answer is: What should happen if the producer stated things are "done" while the queue is non-empty? The usual answer is: The works should drain the queue and terminate when done. Assuming this is the goal, the inner loop would look something like this (while having `mutex` locked: `while (this->queue.empty()) { if (this->done_) { bail_out(); } this->condition_.wait(lock); }` where `bail_out()` is a suitable approach to get out of the loop (`break`, `return`, `throw`...).

Answer (score 0):

Look at the following code:

```
while(!data.empty()){
    segment seg;
    data.wait_and_pop( seg );
    ...
```

Consider a situation where the last segment of data is to be read. And comsumers `th1` & `th2` are waiting for data to be read.

Consumer `th1` checks for `!data.empty()` and finds there is data to be read. Then before `th1` calls `data.wait_and_pop()`, consumer `th2` checks for `!data.empty()` and finds it to be true. Assume comsumer `th1` consumes the last segment. Now, since there is no segment to be read, `th2` waits indefinitely on `the_queue.empty()` in `data.wait_and_pop()`.

Try this code instead of the snippet above:

```
segment seg;
while(data.try_pop(seg)){
    ...
```

Should get it working.

Comment: No this didn't work for me. In fact it resulted in having the consumer threads quitting without doing any work at all. I may have misinterpreted you suggestion however.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to add a boolean flag to `concurrent_queue`. Set it (under the mutex) once the file is read. Once the file is read *and* the queue is empty, broadcast the condition variable from the consumer that emptied the queue using `notify_all`.

This will wake up all the other consumers, which need to spot the final condition (flag set and queue empty) and quit their loop. To avoid the race condition, that means they need to check the same combined condition before waiting in the first place.

The problem with your existing flag is that threads that never wake out of waiting for the condvar, never check it. The "finished" flag needs to be part of the state that they're waiting for.

[Edit: Dietmar's subtly different meaning for the flag probably results in simpler code, but I haven't written them both to compare.]

Comment: I am using std::atomic<bool> as a completion flag but it is not giving me the desired result. Can you spot what I am doing wrong?

Comment: @user841550: updated. The hung threads are in `wait_and_pop`, right? If not then I've misunderstood something.